# What path do I use for my .txt file to get a FileReader to read it?

Tags: java, file

I've placed my .txt file inside the folder for the package (right next to the  .java file) and have this code. Java says the file can't be found.

```
public static void qnaReader()
    {
        String fileName = "QNA.txt";
        FileReader qna = new FileReader(fileName);
    }
```

Is there a specific format for the file path? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need add the file under `src` folder(relative path) or use a absolute path

Comment: You can't access it as a `File` anymore, it will become an embedded source.  Use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` to access it.  The path will be relative to the `Class`'s package used to find the resource

Comment: For any program, in any language, the default working directory is where the program is run. If you want to access a file in another directory you have to either use a relative path, or an absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute your program, Java resolve relative path (which QNA.txt is) by the using the current working directory (`$PWD` in bash).

- You need to change the working directory to that of the folder in which you Java file is contained
- You may also use `Class::getResourceAsStream` which may return `null` if the resource is not found.

You may read the javadoc of `getResourceAsStream` for explanation of what it does and how.

```
InputStream is = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("QNA.txt");
if (null != is) {
  try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
    ... 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For your application to read a file (just about any file), you have two ways to do so:

First Method

Supply the full path. Example: /home/oOVOo/QNA.txt. If you are running Windows: D:/folder/QNA.txt. It's okay to use `/` when specifying a path on Windows. The JVM reads the path and decides which separator to use based on the underlying OS.

Second Method

Supply the relative path based on the current working directory as seen by the application. Meaning, if you are running the application from a directory or a folder called "foo" and then, the text file has to be in that directory in order to supply the relative path which is then the file name `QNA.txt`.

Hope you find this answer useful.

Answer (score 1):

In the provided example you use a relative filepath. It's relevant if you lookup your file at the "bottom" of classpath or a directory where you run your application from. E.g. in maven project you could place your file in the "src/main/resources" directory and the code above should successfully find it.

Also you can provide an absolute path (not recommended) as:

```
String fileName = "/home/myUser/QNA.txt";
```